# npm err code eisdir errno -4068 whenever installing any package

Tags: node.js, npm, bower

I followed [this](http://abdelraoof.com/blog/2014/11/11/install-nodejs-without-admin-rights/) guide to install node to my machine without having admin rights.

I put node.exe, (npm.cmd and node_modules ) both from the npm zip in C:\Users\rakibler\Node.  I added that to my path.  I ran `npm install -g bower` and got

```
npm ERR! Error: EISDIR, open 'C:\Users\rakibler\Node\bower'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this *entire* log,
npm ERR! including the npm and node versions, at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\rakibler\\Node\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\rakibler\\Node\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "bower"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\rakibler
npm ERR! node -v v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.9
npm ERR! path C:\Users\rakibler\Node\bower
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\rakibler\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

at the end.  It also seems like something else is wrong, because everything it downloads goes to `C:\Users\rakibler\Node` instead of `C:\Users\rakibler\Node\node_modules`.  Not sure what's going wrong here.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to install the npm globlally  using 
     "npm install -g npm"

and then use it in directory to install bower . i hope this will solve your issue

Comment: So I'm marking this as the answer since it's the only one, but if anybody else is curious, me issue is that I accidentally changed my cache directory to something write protected.